# Legend in for loop does not work properly and just shows the last curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I try to putthe labels of `7` curves inside the legend, but when plots are shown the label of 7th curve is on the plot and the other 6 curves do not have any labels.

I tried to use `plt.legend()` in different indentation,  but inside the 3rd for loop we have more than 7 labels because for loop of `z` like `1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3...` in other for loops the legend cannot appear.

we should have `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`.
Any help please?

```
for x in range(len(ng)):
    fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(9,6))
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5,hspace=0.1)
    for xx in range(1,819):
            Ju_list=[]
            ET_list=[]
            ET1_list=[]
            Unu_list=[]
            z_list=[]
            uf_list=[]
            for z in np.arange(0,11):
                    Ju = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]
                    Jl = dfimppara.iloc[xx, 2]
                    lim = Ju - Jl
                    if lim > 1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        if Ju<8:

                            Ju_list.append(dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1])
                            T = ET(xx, z, ng[x], 1e-24, Tg[x], 1)
                            BC = Bcmb(xx,z)
                            Btex = B(xx,T)
                            ET_list.append(1-BC/Btex)
                            z_list.append(z)              
                            l1,=ax1.plot(z_list, ET_list)

                            ax1.title.set_text(f'UF=1e-24,Tg={Tg[x]},ng={ng[x]}')
                            ax1.set_ylabel('1-BB(CMB)/BB(Tex)')
                            ax1.set_xlabel('z')
                            plt.legend([l1],[f'{dfimppara.iloc[xx, 1]}'])


                        else:
                            pass

    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should consider creating your empty lists outside of your for loop, otherwise they will be recreated each iteration (unless that's what you want).

Regarding your legend problem, i suggest you add the 'label' argument to each plot() command, then legend() will create one on its own.

Example:

```
# [...]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x_data, y_data, label='Some label')  
plt.plot(more_x_data, more_y_data, label='Some other label')
plt.legend()
```

Will produce a legend containing each label.
Be aware of the data that is appended to your lists during each iteration of your loops.

Comment: I did this in my code but I have still problem `plt.figure()` before `ax1.plot(....)`. but I get this error No handles with labels found to put in legend`